# I have an error in install of opencv in ananconda

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like someone having the same issue here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8817. To solve it the problem he change the `channel_priority` to `strict`.

> channel_priority (ChannelPriority)
>
> Accepts values of 'strict', 'flexible', and 'disabled'. The default
>    value is 'flexible'. With strict channel priority, packages in lower
>    priority channels are not considered if a package with the same name
>    appears in a higher priority channel.

Source : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html

You can change it using this command

```
$ conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

Comment: I have done but I faced with                                                                                       
 Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.